# Are Xbox One Live Gold cards region locked?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I'm on a trip in another country and I found Xbox One Live Gold for a much better price. Can I use them without changing my region?

I'm talking about Live subscription cards, not Microsoft Points cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It depends on the country.
The ones I buy work in EU and North America but not Russia.